# Why am I getting this vector question wrong about finding the angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

EDIT: this question is about how to use trig to find the angle between the x-axis and a vector. Just editing since stack exchange asked me to clarify what concept I am asking about.

This is a first year physics problem, I'm studying for my exam and am doing some practice and a bit of help would be appreciated for this question. My answer is very close to the answer key but still wrong, and I want to know how and why.

Here is the problem

> If the velocity vector of a polar bear is ($\vec u = -18.0 \hat i - 13.0\hat j$)
> , how fast and in what
> geographic direction is it heading? Here, $\hat i$ and $\hat j$ are directions to geographic east and north, respectively

What I've gotten so far is I've used the cosine law $\vec u 
 \cdot \hat i = |\vec u||\hat i|cos\theta$ to find that

$-18 = (\sqrt{493})(1)cos\theta $

$-0.8106792284 = cos\theta $

$\theta = cos^{-1}(-0.8106792284) $

$\theta = 144.162347$

which I work out to be $35.8^{\circ}$ north of west, **but the answer is $35.8^{\circ}$ south of west.**

My error probably has something to do with the fundamentals of trig but just for context, I'm studying for a deferred exam so I haven't touched any math or physics material for about 18 months!

Comment: thank you both for the answers, they were both very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:

$$\cos(\theta)=-0.81067...$$

so one of the solutions is:

$$\theta = \cos^{-1}(-0.81067) = 144.16 \deg$$

but remember:

$$\cos(\theta)=\cos(-\theta)$$
so both $\theta$ and $-\theta$ give the same answer (similar to how $x^2=1$ has two solutions. So the other solution is:
$$\theta = -\cos^{-1}(-0.81067) = -144.16 \deg$$

Which is what you're looking for. How do you know which one to choose? well since both $i$ and $j$ are negative, then you know it has to be somewhere south-west, which is the second solution.

Comment: ahhh yes thank you :) I forgot everything about trig and its ref angles but this made me remember a lot!

Answer (score 0):

$\cos^{-1}(-x) = \pi-cos^{-1}{x}$

This answer applies when you are trying to find the solution in the principal branch. You could have checked the sign by drawing the vector in the cartesian coordinate system.

I use the formula $\theta = \tan^{-1}{\dfrac{y}{x}}$. We know that both sines and cosines are negative in the third quadrant; hence, the angle should also lie between $\pi$ and $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$.

I suggest not relying on calculators for these calculations as the answers you get are only in the principal branch.

Comment: ahh yes i think what you are describing is the CAST system that they use in our high schools here in canada, but I had totally forgotten! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, we memorise it using the phrase, "Add Sugar To Coffee" where all are positive in the first quadrant, Sine is positive in the second, Tan in the third and Cos in the fourth.